# Elasticsearch clientBuilder not found

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to implement Elastic search using PHP. I have installed `"elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^8.0"`

Basically I have 2 files. `index.php` & inside src folder `init.php`

### index.php

```
<?php
    require_once 'src/init.php';
?>
```

### init.php

```
require_once "./vendor/autoload.php";

use ElasticSearch\ClientBuilder;
$client = ClientBuilder::create()
->setHosts(['localhost:9200'])
->setBasicAuthentication($username, $password)
->build();
```

I am getting following error `Uncaught Error: Class "ElasticSearch\ClientBuilder" not found`

My Project structure

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Please let us know where your composer.json is and subsequently where composer packages get installed to.

Comment: @ChristianM I have added my project structure in my question. `index.php` & `composer.json` are in the same level along with vendor folder

Comment: Thanks for that @nas I just realise, isn't the class actually `Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder` ?

Comment: @ChristianM  `use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;` This is correct path. Even if I use `Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder` returns same error.

Comment: Perhaps you need to do a `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Can it be because of  setHosts & setBasicAuthentication

Comment: @ChristianM it worked automatically. Thanks.. I got another question. I will make another question

Answer (score 3):

Elastic Search recently changed the location of `ClientBuilder` in their package. You'll have to update your `use` statement.

Change this:

`use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;`

to this:

`use Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`use Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;`

Answer (score 2):

Use on top the page to solve this.

```
use Elastic\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;
```